# the data dont display when i run project

Tags: angular, typescript, http, observable

I am a beginner on angular, I tried to use `http` to get data from my backend.
So I have my `user.component.html` like this:

```
  <tr *ngFor="let item of transporter.liste">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.prenom}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
```

I have a service like:

```
getList():Observable<Transporter>{
return this.http.get<Transporter>("http://localhost:9000/users/list")
.pipe(
  tap(transporter=>console.log(transporter))
);
```

I have a class like:

```
export class Transporter{
error: string;
success: string;
liste: [];
objet: {};
constructor(error:string, success:string,liste:[],objet:{}){
    this.error=error;
    this.success=success;
    this.liste=liste;
    this.objet=objet;
}
```

}

and finally the user component

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
transporter:any; 
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onGetUsers();
    console.log(this.transporter);
    }
    onGetUsers():void{
    this.userService.getList()
    .subscribe(
    (response)=>{this.transporter=response; },
    (error)=>console.log(error),
    ()=>console.log("Done")
    );
    }
```

}

please someone can help me to understand what wrong

Comment: i think you will have an error on console, I see when you run the project `transporter.liste` is not defined. Can you please check?

Comment: This is correct, the console.log  in ngoninit show me undefined but after (response)=>{this.transporter=response; }, i have the data

Comment: if you have a broken code in the first go it doest not get the correct values later. Please put an ngIf or make it with async pipe if you plan to make the variable as observable

Answer (score 0):

Just check the transporter is defined before you use nested data:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="transporter">
  <tr *ngFor="let item of transporter.liste">
...
</ng-container>
```